# "Failed to open stream" in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I installed Laravel and create new project. After I tryed use

```
php artisan serv
```

I have the error

```
PHP Warning:  require(/home/michal/Pobrane/blog/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/michal/Pobrane/blog/artisan on line 18
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/home/michal/Pobrane/blog/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/michal/Pobrane/blog/artisan on line 18
```

How can I solve my problem?

Comment: Did you run the composer install?

Comment: Yes. I installed composer and updated that

Comment: Did you check for vendor directory into your root directory?

Comment: Hey, could you run `tree -L 1` and update your answer with the output so we know a little about the directory you are working in?